# How do I assemble and combine video data chunks in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, alamofire, nsdata

I have a very large video file and I have split the video NSDATA in chunks of 5mb, but now I want to assemble all those chunks into a single NSDATA again in original format so I can test that the video doesn't get corrupted or no chunk is lost or no data is lost, So I need to test these cases any help would be appreciated, This is what am doing right now

```
var newData: Data = Data()


for chunk in chunks {
    self.newData.append(chunk)
}
```

just need to know would this will work?

Comment: Instead of doing it yourself let system do it. Make it HLS and AVPlayer will assemble the chunks automatically

Comment: Actually I need to assemble it again in one NSDATA to use in other use cases as well not just for playing video

Comment: Test it... Is there an actual problem or error message?